# Cordova Camera - Ionic

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, yeoman, ionic-framework

I've been looking up for a solution for up to almost 2 days.
I'm trying to use the ngCordova Camera plugin.

I'm using the ionic-yeoman framework with AngularJS.

What I did was:

```
bower install --save ngCordova.
```

Added `ngCordova` to my `app.module`.
Installed the cordova camera plugin:

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.camera.
```

My controller:

```
.controller('profileCtrl', function($scope, myService, $cordovaCamera)
{
  $scope.takePicture = function() {
    var options = { 
        quality : 75, 
        destinationType : Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL, 
        sourceType : Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA, 
        allowEdit : true,
        encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
        targetWidth: 100,
        targetHeight: 100,
        popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
        saveToPhotoAlbum: false
    };

    $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageData) {
      // Success! Image data is here
    }, function(err) {
      // An error occured. Show a message to the user
    });
  }

  myService.getFoo().then(function(data) {
   //this will execute when the 
   //AJAX call completes.
   $scope.items = data;
  });
})
```

And I get this error:ReferenceError: `Camera is not defined`

Comment: When you are on the browser the capabilities of cordova aren't available, just on a deployed app or in the simulator.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you are serving your app through **browser**, whatever you use of `cordova` regarding the usage of device, doesn't work. But, if you are having the problem even after serving your app in emulator or the device itself. Try the following steps.

**Firstly, check the cordova plugin lists:**

Go to project directory type: `cordova plugin lists`

1. see for `cordova-plugin-media-capture`, `cordova-plugin-camera` (if these are not in the list, you are simply missing your plugins). 
   Run the command 
   `cordova  plugin add cordova-plugin-media-capture` and `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera`
2. If the plugins are there and you are still having the issue of camera is not defined

   - `cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-camera`
   - `cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-media-capture`
   - `ionic platform rm android`
   - `ionic platform add android`
   - `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera`
   - `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-media-capture`

Following must be present in your index.html

```
 <script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should make sure you include the `ng-cordova.js` file (from the `ngCordova/dist/`folder) *before* the `cordova.js` file in your html.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you include ngCordova in the controller declaration as well. becoz i had kept my controllers and app.js files seperately and had not included ngCordova in angular.module('xx.controllers', ['ionic','ngCordova']). once i did it my problem was solved and i coul runn the app in genymotion

Answer (score 0):

Just figured this out by analyzing the [Ionic Camera example project](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-example-cordova-camera). You did all of the setup correctly, but you still need to inject it into the controller, like so:

```
.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, Camera) {
```

Note that there is not a dollar sign before `Camera`. This really should be documented more explicitly.

Also, add this factory if you don't already have it:

```
.factory('Camera', ['$q', function($q) {

  return {
    getPicture: function(options) {
      var q = $q.defer();

      navigator.camera.getPicture(function(result) {
        // Do any magic you need
        q.resolve(result);
      }, function(err) {
        q.reject(err);
      }, options);

      return q.promise;
    }
  }
}])
```

Comment: Nope, this is called Factory

Answer (score 0):

just try **ionic run browser** instead **ionic serve**