# Ionic camera plugin issues

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

i am using ionic's plugin camera, i installed it

```
ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-camera
```

then i added it to my controller

```
.controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope, $ionicModal, $timeout, $localStorage, $ionicPlatform, $cordovaCamera) {
```

then i make us of it on a method call takePicture

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    var options = {
        quality: 50,
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
        sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
        allowEdit: true,
        encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
        targetWidth: 100,
        targetHeight: 100,
        popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
        saveToPhotoAlbum: false
    };
     $scope.takePicture = function() {
        $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageData) {
            $scope.registration.imgSrc = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
        }, function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        });

        $scope.registerform.show();

    };
});
```

the problem is in my object call options, i look in the console and it says that

```
Camera is not defined

var options = {
    quality: 50,
    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
    sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
    allowEdit: true,
    encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
    targetWidth: 100,
    targetHeight: 100,
    popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
    saveToPhotoAlbum: false
};
```

i dont know what to do, because i already injected my cordova camera service into my controller, please i hope you can help me
thanks in advance

**Edit 1**

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
<title></title>

<link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
<link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
-->

<!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="lib/ionic/js/angular/angular-resource.min.js"></script>

<script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js"></script>
<!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
<script src="cordova.js"></script>

<!-- your app's js -->
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
<script src="js/services.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="conFusion">
<ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you show your index.html

Comment: i updated it to show index.html

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25000064/cordova-camera-ionic/33514060#33514060 i have already given my answer there.

Comment: You should put `takePicture` method in `deviceready`.

Comment: @AntonioKida Platform ready function is in your app.js? Could you post you apk so that we can install on check in device?